# How to determine the validity of the following inequality?

Tags: integration, analysis, inequality

Let $h_m=\int_0^1 \rho^{m+1} w(\rho) d \rho, \quad m \geq 0$.

When  $\frac{h_{2 m}}{h_{2(m-1)}} \geq \frac{m}{m+1} \frac{h_{2(m+1)}}{h_{2 m}}$ and $m \geq n$ , I want to obtain
$$
h_{2 n} h_{2 m} \geq \frac{n}{m+1} h_{2(n-1)} h_{2(m+1)} .
$$

I attempted to utilize the monotonicity of $h$, but could not obtain the inequality as described above.

This question arises from page 160 of the article "Weissler and Bernoulli type inequalities in Bergman spaces, doi.org/10.1007/s00013-023-01876-9".

Comment: What are you looking for? What is the context of the question?

Comment: I want the last inequality to hold.

Comment: What is $w$? And is it possible for you to provide a link to the paper?

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1007/s00013-023-01876-9. w is an abstract weight, but I believe it doesn't need to be considered when calculating

Comment: Try to multiply the inequality from $n$ to $m$?

Comment: I have also tried, but unfortunately, I did not obtain the corresponding results. I am also not sure if the monotonicity of h is necessary.

Comment: I think after multiplication and elimination, the inequality just becomes $\frac{h_{2 m}}{h_{2(n-1)}} \geq \frac{n}{m+1} \frac{h_{2(m+1)}}{h_{2n}}$.

Comment: Do you mean  $\frac{h_{2 m}h_{2n}}{h_{2(m-1)}h_{2(n-1)}} \geq \frac{m}{m+1}  \frac{n}{n+1} \frac{h_{2(m+1)}}{h_{2 m}}\frac{h_{2(n+1)}}{h_{2 n}}$?

Comment: Well, I think that the original statement means “the inequality holds for all $m \geq n$” , so you can multiply all such inequality from $n$ to a certain $m$, maybe I misunderstood.